# How to close bottom navigation or call another empty activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

This one activity but i try to close the bottom navigation when the user selected one of the side menu fragment. Example when i click my account the bottom not hide.

[image]
[image]

```
       @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_account:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new AccountFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_support:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SupportFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_aboutus:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new AboutusFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Signin.class));
            break;

    }

    mDrawerlayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I hope that will simple code or maybe add another activity?

This my layout

```
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".sidemenu">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:id="@+id/nav_View"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/Black"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/gray"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Maybe put some code in navigation or bottom navigation

Comment: You want to hide this bottom bar when you open the account fragment. 
Please share your activity layout as well

Comment: @KishanMaurya.Yes or another option . i'v update the question

Comment: Please upvote the answer if problem is resolved

Answer (score 2):

As your container and BottomNavigation in same activity layout and you are using your container for fragment.

Create one interface

```
public interface IBottomBarListener{
public void showBottomBar();
public void hideBottomBar()
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity and override these two methods.

```
    public void showBottomBar(){
    // make your bottom bar visibility visible
    }

public void hideBottomBar(){
    // make your bottom bar visibility gone
    }
```

Now in your fragment declare global variable

```
public IBottomBarListener listener;
```

Now in onAttach() method , init your listener

```
listener = (IBottomBarListener)context
```

now in onCreateView(), call

```
listener.hideBottomBar()  // this will hide your bottombar
```

also in onDetach() method, if you want to again make visible your bottombar,

```
onDetach(){
listener.showBottomBar() // this will show your bottombar
}
```

This is basically showing/hiding your bottombar from your fragment. So do same in all fragment from where you want to perform this action.

Comment: this method put in class?

Comment: which method? please